# No readline support for psql after using anaconda to install postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, readline

I installed postgres with my conda package manager

```
conda install postgres
```

But when I connect to my DB at the command line (using Terminal on a Mac) via psql, none of the readline functions work (e.g., up arrow doesn't retrieve previous command).  Is this normal?  What should I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be a problem with anaconda

```
conda uninstall postgresql
```

Install homebrew to get a postgres version that works with readline

```
brew install postgresql
```